# get all indexes of value nil in array

Tags: arrays, ruby, performance, sorting, memory-efficient

I have an array of `N` elements and this array contains either `0`, `1` or `nil`.
I want to get all indexes at which `nil` is present or sort the array so that all `nil` comes first.

I am looking for an efficient way because the array size can be very large.

Here is my code

```
array_of data # array with lots of 1, 0 and nil
temp = []
array_of_data.each_with_index {|a,i| (array_of_data[i] ? true : temp << i )}
```

Comment: CPU-efficient or memory-efficient?

Comment: both if possible but more importantly CPU-efficient.

Comment: Do you need the original array to be preserved?

Comment: actually i will try both ways preserving original array and not preserving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatives for you to benchmark:

```
# Indices of non-nil values
res = ary.map.with_index{ |v,i| i if v }.compact
res = [].tap{ |r| ary.each.with_index{ |v,i| r<<i if v } }
ary.map!.with_index{ |v,i| v && i }.compact

# Sorting the array so that nil comes first (possibly re-ordering the others)
res = ary.sort_by{ |v| v ? 1 : -1 }
ary.sort_by!{ |v| v ? 1 : -1 }

# Sorting the array so that nil comes first, order of others unchanged
res = ary.sort_by.with_index{ |v,i| v ? i : -1 }
ary.sort_by!.with_index{ |v,i| v ? i : -1 }
```

Comment: `each.with_index` or each_with_index?